# I have a group button in node puppeteer but i want to press Simple button.It does not response.What is the solution now?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a group button in node puppeteer but I want to press a Simple button. It does not respond. What is the solution now?
Here is a code.

```
   await page.waitForSelector('#search_add_record_btn')
        .then(async () => {
            await page.click('#search_add_record_btn')
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            console.log("Button Clicked")
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log('Error is search add button record :' + e);
        });
```

This is the button:
[image: This is the button]

```
<button type="button" id="search_add_record_btn" class="btn btn-primary add-record-btn" ng-disabled="manage.adding_record || manage.editing_record || manage.is_loading" ng-click="manage.open_add_record()"> <span class="fas fa-plus"></span> Add Record</button>
```

Comment: You should also add HTML code

Comment: There is only a simple group button image below this code.I used id for click.

Comment: <button type="button" id="search_add_record_btn" class="btn btn-primary add-record-btn" ng-disabled="manage.adding_record || manage.editing_record || manage.is_loading" ng-click="manage.open_add_record()">
                    <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>
                    Add Record</button>

Comment: What happens with the code you’ve provided? Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Note that there’s no need to use `then` here; you can use `try`/`catch` since you’re using `async`/`await`.